# How can I save the value selected from a spinner that would change if the device's language change?

Tags: android, spinner

So this one is very difficult I guess.

I've been trying all means and all of my knowledge, so after searching all the web and this site I have to ask the question.

Here is the deal:

I have a spinner that has as values (in English) say:
bees
birds
squirrels

In spanish the values will be:

abejas
pajaros
ardillas

I make sure they are the same because at runtime I construct the values going into the spinner from a file called

store.xml

```
<resources>
   <string name="bees">bees</string>
   <string name="birds">birds</string>
   <string name="squirrels">squirrels</string>
   <string name="other_species">other species</string>
</resources>
```

and under the folder values-es

store.xml

```
<resources>
   <string name="bees">abejas</string>
   <string name="birds">pajaros</string>
   <string name="squirrels">ardillas</string>
   <string name="other_species">otra especie</string>
</resources>
```

The problem is that I shouldn't save the actual value selected by the user, because when they change the device's language, then the value saved it would be in a different language.

So I thought in a way of getting the unique Id of the string value selected by the user and I used res.getIdentifier to get the Id and then the name of the string resource.  THEN I would save the name of the resource in the database, that way if the language changed I would be able to locate the value based on the name.

Now, res.getIdentifier worked, as long as the value was the same as the name i.e.:

```
  value "bees", name="bees" (works)
  value "bees", name="abejas" (don't work)
  value "other_species", name="other species" (don't work)
```

So is there a way that I can get to the name of a string in an xml, from the value?

Or is there another workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

You could fill your spinner with ids rather than strings, and use a custom adapter to display the strings. That way the logic is language independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but how can I exactly accomplish this?  If I fill the spinner with the Ids, I think it would be shown instead of the strings they should appear. Besides that, I learned to fill the spinner with an adapter, so I don't know how to separate both. However, I'll investigate how to do it.  Thanks, really.

Comment: A custom adapter can generate whatever view it wants from the values. The ArrayAdapter simply fills the view with the object.toString(). Implement an adapter that extends ArrayAdapter (of ids) and override getView.

Answer (score 0):

Use another array as a mapping for example:

```
English  Language A  
   0         2
   1         3
   2         0
   3         1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :-).  I might not be as experience programmer as I thought because I am having a hard time understanding how to implement it.